# Silverlight 5 screen detection

Tags: silverlight, mono, cross-platform, silverlight-5.0

How do I detect multiple screens on Windows and Mac from a Silverlight 5 out-of-browser application?

I'm looking at Silverlight 5 for a Winodws/Mac application I would like to build. Now that Silverlight [supports multiple windows](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/05/silverlight-5-multiple-window-support.html) when running in out-of-browser mode this seems like a decent option based on my own knowledge of WPF and .NET.

I noticed that `Windows.Forms` namespace is missing (which makes perfect sense) but that leaves me with the above question I can't seem to find an answer for.

I've thought about using a Mono project for this, but haven't dug up a method from their either, still searching though. I'm not looking for the *best* way, just *any* way.

FYI, the purpose of screen detection is to have a second window set full screen for display of material via a projector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences in behavior of [Silverlight out-of-browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd550721%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) applications between Mac and Windows, see [Silverlight Differences on Windows and Macintosh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838247%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). It is possible to detect the platform the application is running on and only make valid calls for the host platform.

Pete Brown's article [Creating Big Silverlight Windows and Getting Monitor Resolutions and Positions with PInvoke](http://10rem.net/blog/2012/02/07/creating-big-silverlight-windows-and-getting-monitor-resolutions-and-positions-with-pinvoke) describes how to get display information on the Windows platform via the Win32 [EnumDisplayMonitors](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumDisplayMonitors) and [GetMonitorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) functions.

Silverlight is still a good option if you want to develop a .Net application with C#/F#/VB.Net that runs on both Windows and Mac, another is [Mono](http://xamarin.com/).

Comment: Do you know if PInvoke works on Mac? I thought about using a separate java app that could write the screen info to an ini like file for the Mac version.

Comment: @agrothe sorry my knowledge of Silverlight on Mac is limited

Comment: I like the Silverlight/WPF for the text scaling it provides. Mono was my 2nd option, but it's not as RAD as Silverlight, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find an answer.

It seems that on Windows, you can achieve this with [win32](http://purplestoat.com/blog/positioning-a-window-in-a-second-monitor-in-silverlight-5-2/). However, the solution depends on p/invoke, which is not available on Silverlight for Mac.

I doubt that there is a solution in managed code, that will run in Silverlight, in either .NET or Mono.

Also, I would question the decision to start a new application in Silverlight; since version 5 appears to be the [end of the line](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2011/12/silverlight-5-released-will-there-be-a-silverlight-6/) for that framework.

Comment: I understand it appears to be end of line, but vb6 is still available to code in :). Not saying anyone *should* though. I was hoping to create a quick multi-platform via silverlight. Java is my other option I guess but its not something I've done much of.